# Python thread generate tasks increasingly and consume too much memory and cpu

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I have a file with a specific task and I need to run it every 1 second. I wrote the program below and make this file as a service in linux. As I start the service, python thread generates task increasingly which consumes too much CPU and Memory. Because the maximum number of tasks in linux is limited, after that total of tasks goes beyond the maximum, the service will be crashes

> As you see in this picture, the number of tasks increasing by time and very high memory and CPU usage!!!

[image: My Service Info]

```
threads = []
def process():
    t = threading.Timer(interval=1, function=process)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
    do_task()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process()

    for thd in threads:
        thd.join()
```

**My Question**: How can I limit my thread? How can I make sure no new tasks generate before the other task is running?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to limit my thread. Like no new tasks generates before other task is running yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written there looks like a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) or at least very very close to it

Your `process` function keeps spawning threads that run the same function inside of it, and only THEN running the actual job it's supposed to. This means you end up with a huge number of threads in a very short amount of time. A quick fix in the right direction would be to do the work first, then spawn another thread, like so:

```
def process():
    do_task()
    t = threading.Timer(interval=1, function=process)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
```

The important thing to note here is that `do_task()` is executed before any additional threads are being created

That being said, why is it that you need an extra thread for the work at hand and won't settle for `time.sleep` instead?

```
import time
while True:
  time.sleep(1)
  do_work()
```

While this won't guarantee that you get the job done exactly once every second, you have a constant memory footprint, and if the job takes too long you don't run out of resources either

Answer (score 0):

This is what I call *threadomania.* It's a craziness. Each spawned thread keeps spawning new threads, and this keeps going on and on almost for eternity which causes resource starvation:

```
def process():
    t = threading.Timer(interval=1, function=process)
    t.start()
   ...
```

what you're basically doing is spawning threads with timers that run `process` after the specified interval elapses. The question is when does that stop? You might be using `os._exit` in `do_task` to kill the whole process but highly unlikely and even worse, don't do it unless you know what you're doing! I can't tell. But here's what I can say, you're making a pool of worker threads to do tasks and that shouldn't be done uncontrollably. I've fine-tuned your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    numOfThreads = 10             # 10 threads
    for i in range(numOfThreads):
        t = threading.Timer(interval=1, function=do_task)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

   for t in threads:
       t.join()
```

You have intermixed some portions of your code that should really be outside spawned threads, your spawned threads should do the blocking or long running tasks.